# Android Recyclerview item side by side

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have recycler-view with items in it and can be scrolled vertically. Currently what i achieved is items are added one after another like a list. By i need to place them side by side.

**Like the image below**

[image: Target]

**And my output is**

[image: Output]

**My recycler-view setup code:**

```
topicAdapter = new TopicAdapter(topicList, getActivity());
        topicListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        topicListView.setAdapter(topicAdapter);
```

**and adapter code is:**

```
public class TopicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TopicAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {
    private List<Topic> topicList;
    Context context;

    public TopicAdapter(List<Topic> topicList, Context context) {
        this.topicList = topicList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflate the layout file
        View groceryProductView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_suggested_topics, parent, false);
        CategoryViewHolder holder = new CategoryViewHolder(groceryProductView);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txtview.setText(topicList.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return topicList.size();
    }

    public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtview;

        public CategoryViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            txtview = view.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733221/android-horizontal-recyclerview-scroll-direction

Comment: `setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));`

Comment: They've added Chip in support library 28. [1](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) [2](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-the-v28-android-design-support-library-2c96c6031ae8)

Comment: add your adapter layout code it means adapter in define layout xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Google's latest design component [ChipGroup](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#choice-chips)

Else you can use [Flexbox-Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) by showing your tags in Grid Layout. 
If you wish to go for Flexbox-Layout, check [answer of avik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47587458/3762067)

Comment: i have achieved this by using flexbox. but any idea how can i center the elements? 

This is my current output : https://imgur.com/5oGHiMW

Comment: Yes just `JustifyContent.CENTER` like `flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);`

Comment: But you may also have to set `layout_gravity` attribute to your RecyclerView `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you with a simple solution but, you cant achieve complete requirement with this code. You'll get side by side.

Replace

```
topicListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

with

```
topicListView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3)); 

// 3 denotes the number of rows per column
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This

```
  topicListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
```

Comment: This does not solve his problem, this will make them horizontal but in single file. He wants it to be on multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do this is by using [Material Choice Chips](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#choice-chips), you can learn how to use them [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/). You can then use a [ChipGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup) to group them and allow them to flow across multiple lines.

However, to solve your question at hand, you can use a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager) and then supply a [SpanSizeLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup).

Answer (score 0):

Use StaggeredGridLayoutManager for recyclerview